# Python - How to quickly find the index of multiple vectors in an array

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 large arrays, `A` and `B`, and I want to find where the vectors of `A` are in `B`. I have to find 10,000, 1 x 800 vectors among 40,000 vectors of the same size.

Example

```
A = [[1,2],[2,3],[4,5]]
B = [[2,3],[4,5]]
```

Desired Output:

```
[1,2]
```

I can find a single vector using `np.argwhere((A == B[0]).all(-1))` but I am not sure how to shape the arrays to find the indices of each vector. I can use a for loop but that is too slow. For example

```
np.asarray([np.argwhere((A == B_[i]).all(-1)) for i in range(np.shape(A)[0])])
```

Comment: You haven't specified the shapes adequately. But, using enumerate, you could create a dictionary from `B`, keyed by the vectors and whose values are the indices where the vector occurs. Something like `d = {v:i for i,v in enumerate(B)}`. That would allow you to just lookup where the vectors occur in `B`

Comment: `How can I do this without a for loop?` - do some research; formulate some strategies; try them out; assess; adjust; reapeat.

Comment: A and B are not the same array. I reworded the question to reflect this.

Comment: I don' want to use enumerate, because it is effectively a for loop. I have roughly 10,000 vectors so using a for loop is not that feasible.

Comment: I mean Python handles for loops quite slowly. I have to find 10,000, 1 x 800 vectors among 40,000 vectors of the same size. I have to do this a couple times. It takes right now two to three minutes for each so roughly 12 minutes.

Comment: With those run times, my guess is that you are using something which has quadratic complexity. My suggestion gets it down to linear.

Comment: Maybe, I am misunderstanding what John is suggesting. Could you clarify?

Comment: What I've been doing as a floor loop is `np.asarray([np.argwhere((A == B_[i]).all(-1)) for i in range(np.shape(A)[0])])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup

```
import numpy as np

rows_a = 40000
rows_b = 10000
size = 800

a = np.arange(rows_a * size).reshape((rows_a, size))
np.random.shuffle(a)
b = np.arange(rows_b * size).reshape((rows_b, size))
```

Solution

```
d = {tuple(v): i for i, v in enumerate(a)}
idx = [d[tuple(row)] for row in b]
```

Let's say that `a` has size `m` and `b` has size `n`.

`d` creates a mapping of the rows in `a` to their index. `tuple(v)` is necessary if `v` is not hashable, like lists and ndarrays. This has O(m) time complexity because you iterable over the rows once.

`idx` iterates over the rows in `b` and checks the dictionary to fetch the respective index in `a`. A dictionary lookup has O(1) time complexity and the loop O(n). All in all, you're looking at O(m+n), which is linear.

What you are doing instead is for each row in `b`, you check *every row* in `a` to find its index. This has O(m*n) complexity, which is quadratic.